# Wrong Orientation with iPhone 6+

Tags: orientation, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, iphone-6-plus

I have an application that supports landscape and portrait orientation.  However, the root view controller only supports portrait.  Here are the two methods that I override for the root view controller.

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The orientation behaves correctly for iphone5/5s/6/6s.  But in the case for the iphone 6+, when I rotate the device landscape and then launch the app, the root view controller is shown in landscape.

OS: iOS9.0
Device: iPhone6+

Comment: I got the same issue, do you have resolved it?